# Creating a loop from Java input

Tags: java, loops

I need to create a loop from user input. For example they have to enter how many times they want to shuffle the cards. And then it will run the loop of the cards being drawn as many times as the user input states. I will apply my entire code.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.Random;

 public class stringVariables { 

 private static boolean isValid;

  public static void main (String[]args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

//user inputs their name in this section






Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);

String first_name;
System.out.print("Enter Your First Name: ");
first_name = user_input.next ();

String last_name;
System.out.print("Enter Your Last Name: ");
last_name = user_input.next ();

String full_name;
full_name = first_name + " " + last_name;

System.out.println( full_name + " Is Now Playing"); 

//this is the shuffle portion as well as something to see if a number is not inputed
 boolean testing = false;
 String pos = "";
 while(true)
 {
 testing = false;   
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("How many times do you want the numbers shuffled: ");
 pos = sc.next();
 for(int i=0; i<pos.length();i++)
 {
     if(!Character.isDigit(pos.charAt(i)))
         testing = true;
 }
 if(testing == true)
 {
     System.out.print("Enter only numbers..   ");
     continue;
 }

 else
 {
     int key = Integer.parseInt(pos);


    break; 








    // here is going to be the loop for shuffles









// we are now going to generate their random number and add a delay after completing their name fields

delay(2000);
System.out.println(" You will be given a hand  of 3 random numbers between 7-13");

delay(2000);
System.out.println(" Then, the computer will add the random numbers and  if it is equal to 31, you win.");









    /* end of explanation of the game, next i will create a new screen
       with the user's name and numbers */


delay(4000);
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(" ");






System.out.println("User playing: " + full_name);

System.out.println("Your lucky numbers are...");



// random number generator 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Random rn = new Random();

int ch=1;
while(ch==1){


// get two random numbers between 7 and 13
Random r = new Random();
int num1 =7 +  (int)(Math.random()*(7));
int num2 = 7 +  (int)(Math.random()*(7));
int num3 = 7 +  (int)(Math.random()*(7));



System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " + " + num3+  " = " + (num1 + num2 + num3 ));

int i = 0 ;
{
    System.out.println( num1 + num2 + num3  );
    i++ ;
} 


 if(num1 + num2 + num3 == 31){ 
    System.out.println("Congratulations !! You are the Lucky Winner !!!!"); 
    }

 else
 System.out.println("Better Luck Next Time");











  //the play again menu. this blocks any input besides 1 or 0


 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 while (true) {
System.out.println("Want To Play Again ? ANY # = YES, ANY LETTER = NO");
String input = sc.next();
int intInputValue = 0;
try {

    intInputValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
    break;
} catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
    System.out.println("Input is not a number, type 1 to continue, or any letter to quit");

    ch=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}

 }}

 }


//delay field

    public static void delay(int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException exp) {

       //delay field 

 }
    }
 }
```

what I need to do is loop the user input from

```
 boolean testing = false;
  String pos = "";
  while(true)
 {
  testing = false;   
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("How many times do you want the numbers shuffled: ");
  pos = sc.next();
  for(int i=0; i<pos.length();i++)
  {
  if(!Character.isDigit(pos.charAt(i)))
     testing = true;
   }
  if(testing == true)
  {
  System.out.print("Enter only numbers..   ");
  continue;
  }

  else
  {
   int key = Integer.parseInt(pos);


break;
```

And make it replay this loop

```
   // random number generator 
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new         InputStreamReader(System.in));
 Random rn = new Random();

 int ch=1;
 while(ch==1){


 // get two random numbers between 7 and 13
 Random r = new Random();
  int num1 =7 +  (int)(Math.random()*(7));
 int num2 = 7 +  (int)(Math.random()*(7));
 int num3 = 7 +  (int)(Math.random()*(7));



 System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " + " + num3+  " = " + (num1 + num2 + num3 ));

 int i = 0 ;
  {
System.out.println( num1 + num2 + num3  );
i++ ;
 }
```

To make it loop to the desired user input after the completion of their name

Comment: Please format your code...

Comment: The task you are trying to complete requires multiple steps. Which one are you stuck at? Do you know how to get input from a user? Do you know how to use a variable in a loop? You might be getting downvoted because you haven't narrowed down your problem to a specific enough question.

Comment: methods are pobably what you are looking for...

Comment: in my program if you run it it will ask how many times do you want the numbers shuffled. if you type 5 i should get 3 numbers between 7-13 appear 5 times

Comment: I agree with @CharlesMcKelvey in that the question is unclear. Also, as a code review item you should consider naming your variables with something more descriptive rather than short two-character names like "ch".

Comment: Also, your code does not compile, there are missing brackets and duplicate local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve I have tried to modify your code from your original post to make it more readable and function the way you want. Please see my comments in the code below, I tried to prefix all of my comments with "EDIT" so you could easily identify which are mine.

```
//EDIT: added new import to help with validating user input
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
//EDIT: removed import that is no longer needed, see code changes below
//import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
//EDIT: removed import that is no longer needed, see code changes below
//import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;

//EDIT: changed class name to java standard naming convention using uppercase for first letter.
public class StringVariables {

    // EDIT: this variable is not used, I removed it
    // private static boolean isValid;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,
            IOException {

        // user inputs their name in this section
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String first_name;
        System.out.print("Enter Your First Name: ");
        first_name = user_input.next();

        String last_name;
        System.out.print("Enter Your Last Name: ");
        last_name = user_input.next();

        String full_name;
        full_name = first_name + " " + last_name;

        System.out.println(full_name + " Is Now Playing");

        // this is the shuffle portion as well as something to see if a number
        // is not inputed
        // EDIT: removed this variable as it is no longer used in the code that
        // follows.
        // boolean testing = false;
        // EDIT: Removed this variable in favor of using Scanner.nextInt() in
        // the code below
        // String pos = "";

        // EDIT: Added this variable and initialized to an invalid value so that
        // we can loop until a valid value is entered.
        int numShuffles = -1;
        while (numShuffles < 0) {
            // EDIT: This variable is not needed with the new logic
            // testing = false;
            // EDIT: This is not needed, you already have a Scanner object above
            // called user_input
            // Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out
                    .println("How many times do you want the numbers shuffled? ");

            try {
                // EDIT: modified the lines below to fix infinite loop, forgot
                // about certain Scanner behavior so switched back to
                // Integer.parseInt
                String inputText = user_input.next();
                numShuffles = Integer.parseInt(inputText);
            } catch (NumberFormatException inputException) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a valid number. ");
            }
        } // EDIT: added closing bracket here
            // EDIT: none of the code commented out below is needed when using
            // the new code above.
        // for(int i=0; i<pos.length();i++)
        // {
        // if(!Character.isDigit(pos.charAt(i)))
        // testing = true;
        // }
        // if(testing == true)
        // {
        // System.out.print("Enter only numbers..   ");
        // continue;
        // }
        //
        // else
        // {
        // int key = Integer.parseInt(pos);
        //
        //
        // break;

        // here is going to be the loop for shuffles

        // we are now going to generate their random number and add a delay
        // after completing their name fields

        delay(2000);
        System.out
                .println(" You will be given a hand  of 3 random numbers between 7-13");

        delay(2000);
        System.out
                .println(" Then, the computer will add the random numbers and  if it is equal to 31, you win.");

        /*
         * end of explanation of the game, next i will create a new screen with
         * the user's name and numbers
         */

        delay(4000);
        // EDIT: rather than repeating the same code over and over just use a
        // loop if you want to print 25 blank lines.
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            System.out.println(" ");
        // EDIT: see previous comment, removed duplicate code
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");
        // System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println("User playing: " + full_name);

        System.out.println("Your lucky numbers are...");

        // random number generator
        // EDIT: This BufferedReader is not needed with changes to code below
        // BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
        // InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Random random = new Random();

        // EDIT: removed the following two lines to simplify the looping logic
        // int ch = 1;
        // while (ch == 1) {
        while (true) {

            // EDIT: your comment is wrong, you're creating 3 numbers here not 2
            // get two random numbers between 7 and 13
            // EDIT: no need to create a new Random inside the loop, you can
            // re-use a single instance.
            // Random r = new Random();
            // EDIT: This approach is fine, but I think using the Random class
            // is easier to read so I replaced your code with code that uses
            // Random
            // int num1 = 7 + (int) (Math.random() * (7));
            // int num2 = 7 + (int) (Math.random() * (7));
            // int num3 = 7 + (int) (Math.random() * (7));

            // EDIT: based on your replies it seems like you want to give the user
            // several changes for each run of the game and this is what you meant
            // by "shuffle". I have implemented that feature below with the for loop.
            boolean isWinner = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < numShuffles; i++) {
                int num1 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);
                int num2 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);
                int num3 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);

                System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " + " + num3 + " = "
                        + (num1 + num2 + num3));

                // EDIT: you never use the variable i so I removed this code.
                // int i = 0;
                // {
                // System.out.println(num1 + num2 + num3);
                // i++;
                // }

                if (num1 + num2 + num3 == 31) {
                    isWinner = true;
                    System.out
                            .println("Congratulations !! You are the Lucky Winner !!!!");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isWinner)
                System.out.println("Better Luck Next Time");

            // the play again menu. this blocks any input besides 1 or 0

            // EDIT: again, re-use the existing scanner
            // Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            // EDIT: There is a much simpler and easier-to-read way to do this
            // so I have removed your code and added new code after.
            // EDIT: Also this code does not work correctly, it fails to exit
            // properly when the user enters a letter.
            // while (true) {
            // System.out.println("Want To Play Again ? ANY # = YES, ANY LETTER = NO");
            // String input = user_input.next();
            // int intInputValue = 0;
            // try {
            //
            // intInputValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
            // Integer.parseInt(input);
            // break;
            // } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
            // System.out.println("Input is not a number, type 1 to continue, or any letter to quit");
            //
            // ch = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            // }
            //
            // }
            // EDIT: here is the new code, see previous comment.
            System.out
                    .println("Do you want to play again? (If you do enter y or yes) ");
            String input = user_input.next();
            if (!"y".equalsIgnoreCase(input) && !"yes".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // EDIT: close the scanner when you're finished with it.
        user_input.close();
    }

    // delay field

    public static void delay(int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException exp) {

            // delay field

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! this has actually taught me more than i expected. thank you. also there is an error, when a non number is placed within the "how many times do you want it shuffled" a loop of "Please enter a valid number.How many times do you want the numbers shuffled? " endlessly replays

Comment: Updated the code in the try-catch block of the `numShuffles` loop

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

```
while(true) {
    try{
        pos = sc.nextInt();
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Use only numbers.");
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
    //do the shuffling 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to fit in with my code, im sorry im a beginner.

Comment: how do i place it into the code? could you show me an example, do i have to create strings within the main, do you think you could place it in the entire code that i placed at the top of the question? it would mean so much

Comment: please if anyone can help. i know i over complicated it

Comment: @e. john I screwed up the syntax. vatsal mevada brought it to my attention. Try it again.

Comment: where do i place this code? do i place is overtop of my current

Comment: @e. john Yes. Put the while loop over your "boolean testing" code and then put your Random number generation in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some altering in your code and I feel this is what you are looking for. Just copy paste the code and it should work *ideally*.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;

public class StringVariables  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        //user inputs their name in this section

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String first_name;
        System.out.print("Enter Your First Name: ");
        first_name = sc.next();

        String last_name;
        System.out.print("Enter Your Last Name: ");
        last_name = sc.next();

        String full_name;
        full_name = first_name + " " + last_name;

        System.out.println(full_name + " Is Now Playing");

//this is the shuffle portion as well as something to see if a number is not inputed


        int ch = 1;
        while (ch == 1) {
            int pos = 0;
            System.out.println("How many times do you want the numbers shuffled: ");
            while (true) {
                sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                try {
                    pos = sc.nextInt();
                    break;
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("Use only numbers.");
                }
            }
            // we are now going to generate their random number and add a delay after completing their name fields

            delay(2000);
            System.out.println(" You will be given a hand  of 3 random numbers between 7-13");

            delay(2000);
            System.out.println(" Then, the computer will add the random numbers and  if it is equal to 31, you win.");


    /* end of explanation of the game, next i will create a new screen
       with the user's name and numbers */


            delay(4000);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                System.out.println(" ");
            }

            System.out.println("User playing: " + full_name);

            System.out.println("Your lucky numbers are...");


// random number generator
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0;
            boolean isWinner = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < pos; j++) {
                num1 = 7 + (int) (Math.random() * (7));
                num2 = 7 + (int) (Math.random() * (7));
                num3 = 7 + (int) (Math.random() * (7));
                System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " + " + num3 + " = " + (num1 + num2 + num3));

                if (num1 + num2 + num3 == 31) {
                    System.out.println("Congratulations !! You are the Lucky Winner !!!!");
                    isWinner = true;
                }
            }

            if(!isWinner){
                System.out.println("Better Luck Next Time");
            }




            //the play again menu. this blocks any input besides 1 or 0


            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Want To Play Again ? ANY # = YES, ANY LETTER = NO");
                String input = sc.next();
                int intInputValue = 0;
                try {

                    intInputValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    break;
                } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
                    System.out.println("Input is not a number, type 1 to continue, or any letter to quit");

                    ch = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                }

            }
        }

    }


//delay field

    public static void delay(int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException exp) {

            //delay field

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't seem to do the user loop for the drawing of the numbers

Comment: @e.john what do you mean by _user loop_? can you elaborate a little more. Do you want to prompt for user name again when user choose to replay?

Comment: sorry for the unclarity. for the loop section i mean it to be ex:
enter number of shuffles:
user: 3
numbers
7 + 9 + 8 + = 24
9 +8+ 7 = 24
7 +11+ 13 = 31

if any of these equal 31 the user should be declared the winner

Comment: @e.john I didn't understand your previous comment.

Comment: so the shuffle is supposed to be like a how many decks do you want to have, kind of like in bingo, if any of the outputted numbers equal 31 the user wins

Comment: so if the user says they want it shuffled 4 times, the 3 random numbers will be printed out 4 times and if any equal 31 they will win, if that makes more sense

Comment: i know my description is broad but i hope you understand, i need help asap

Comment: Updated the code. Try it once and let me know whether that is what you expected.

Comment: Just a side note - the last loop that does `catch (NumberFormatException ne)` does not work as it claims to, if the user enters a letter the program does not exit cleanly. It may exit due to an uncaught exception but that's not good practice.

Comment: yay the code works good as gold. thank you so much, also @D.B. would you be able to help me with closing the program, i didnt know how to do that

Comment: @D.B. yep good point. I didn't looked into any other flaws of the code. I just wanted to make it run.

Comment: @e.john if it worked then you should mark this answer as accepted by checking the tick mark.

Comment: @e.john I suggested a different approach for the exit logic in my answer.